# Chef vault refresh all

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I would like to refresh all my vaults, is there a solution to do this with one command?

E.g.

```
knife vault refresh certs secret1
knife vault refresh certs secret2
..
--> knife vault refresh certs *
```

Answer (score 2):

You can automate using "knife data bag" commands.

Here is how to do it in shell:

```
for i in $(knife data bag list); do 
    for j in $(knife data bag show $i|grep _keys$|sed s/_keys$//); do 
      echo knife vault refresh $i $j
    done
done
```

When you are satisfied with the result, you simply remove the "echo" from 3rd line.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way to do that currently in chef-vault. You must provide both vault and item to refresh command. Alternatively you can create some automated task for that (rake task) so you do not need to manually run multiple commands every time.

You can create feature request on [chef-vault repo](https://github.com/Nordstrom/chef-vault) on GitHub.